# Why Does That JS Code Not Work For Anything Except The First Class On The Page?

Tags: javascript, queryselector

The following JS code turns on/off the in-site search, but there is a `.search-button` button in 2 places on the page, first one works but second one does not work. If I add more, they also do not work. Can I get this code to run on all classes on the page that contain a `.search-button`?

```
var wHeight = window.innerHeight;
var sb = document.querySelector(".search-button");
var closeSB = document.querySelector(".search-close");
var SearchOverlay = document.body;
var searchBar = document.querySelector(".search-bar");
// Show
searchBar.style.top=wHeight/2 +'px';
    console.log(wHeight);
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        console.log(wHeight);
        wHeight = window.innerHeight;
        searchBar.style.top=wHeight/2 + 'px';
    }, true);
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
    sb.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Opened Search for Element: ");
    SearchOverlay.classList.add("show-search");
};
// Hide
closeSB.onclick = function() {
    console.log("Closed Search for Element: " + closeSB);
    SearchOverlay.classList.remove("show-search");
    };
}, true);
```

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? The question says that they all work.

Comment: `document.querySelector()` only returns the first match of the selector. If you want multiple matches you have to use `querySelectorAll()`, and then iterate over the results.

Comment: I did not know the use of querySelectorAll, now it is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using `document.querySelector()` which returns the first element matching your query. For more details check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector.

To query all elements with same class you need to use `document.querySelectorAll()` which returns all elements matching as an array. Then, you can use the array `forEach()` function to iterate over all elements and add event function for all.

```
var sb = document.querySelectorAll(".search-button");

sb.forEach(el => el.onclick = function(e) {
    console.log("Opened Search for Element: ");
    SearchOverlay.classList.add("show-search");
});
```

**Update**: You can also simplify your

Comment: I did not know the use of querySelectorAll, now it is solved. Thanks.